# Sails-mongo not working with MongoDB Atlas URI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js, sails-mongo

I was trying with the below configs :

In `datastores.js` I tried

```
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
url: 'mongodb+srv://xyz@cluster0.uaxyh.mongodb.net/xyz?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
ssl: true
```

The above URL is for MongoDB Atlas

In `model.js`

```
id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' }
```

Did `npm install sails-mongo`

Still I am unable to connect to my **"MongoDB"**

I am using `"sails": "^1.2.4"` ,   `"sails-mongo": "^1.2.0"`

For your Information I would like to tell that I was able to connect to same instance using `Mongoose` adapter.

The **error** I am getting is as below -

```
A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear 
down a datastore (`default`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually 
due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more 
than once), or it could be
due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)
Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager:
MongoError: failed to connect to server [cluster0.uzpih.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect 
[MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0.uzpih.mongodb.net cluster0.uzpih.mongodb.net:27017]
```

Please, suggest me where I am doing wrong! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Correct URL at your **MongoDB atlas** `connection` tab , where you can select `nodejs` driver version `2.2.12 or later`

The Following url worked for me :

```
url: 'mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@DB01-shard-00-00-yxtfo.mongodb.net:27017,DB01-shard-00-01-yxtfo.mongodb.net:27017,DB01-shard-00-02-yxtfo.mongodb.net:27017/DB?ssl=true&replicaSet=DB01-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Replace the correct values with your DB configs and Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try sails-mongo-cloud npm package for sails